# What are some "must-do" vocal exercises to be done everyday?

Tags: voice, vocal-range, exercises, warm-up

For someone who has pitching issues - what are some must-do vocal exercises that you'd suggest that must be done strictly everyday to master pitch perfection. What must be the focus while doing these exercises?

Answer (score 3):

Strange as it may sound, it's breathing exercises that will improve pitch.By the time you think,'oh I'm a little flat' the next note has come along anyway, so thinking about pitching your voice isn't going to help. Think about your stomach (diaphragm) and mouth, and forget about your larynx. Take a good breath, thinking only about your stomach moving down and out, making room for your expanding lungs.
Sing long notes, driving them with your stomach and ignoring your chest and larynx. Mark on your score or lyric sheet the places where you will be breathing, then experiment, and alter your breaths to suit. Now stick to this breathing plan, making sure you always have plenty of air. It's all about air.